# Rigorous Bell-CHSH?

Tags: probability

The usual derivations by physicists of the Bell-CHSH inequalities as a limit imposed on any possible local hidden variables description of quantum systems seems so sloppy, that I'm tempted to ask you statisticians if there is a rigorous mathematical derivation of these results. Also, what would be a proper statistical analysis of the corresponding experiments (such as the one by Aspect et al)?

Comment: [Van Dam et al. (2003)](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0307125) might be of interest.

Comment: What is sloppy? (Example citation needed; ideally with line exact equation or assumption that is sloppy.)